# How to replicate the new toolbar of Play Store & Maps

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar, android-search

The Play store's new toolbar contains a searchview spanning across the toolbar. I tried doing it by importing the AOSP searchview in my project, removing the Magnifying glass icon.

but when in landscape view the search goes to right side & app's title comes on left.

I removed the title but still the searchview stays on right side.

Portrait: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8FQt.png

Landscape: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hA50H.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found this library 'persistent search'. APpears to be exactly like the play store toolbar.

https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1653